# Boost filter_iterator with not DefaultConstructible predicate

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use a Predicate for `boost::filter_iterator` that looks like this:

```
  template<class tuple_t>
  struct exactly {

    tuple_t expected;

    exactly(tuple_t&& expected) : expected(expected) {}
    exactly(const tuple_t& expected) : expected(expected) {}

    template<class actual_tuple_t, class I = make_index_sequence<tuple_size<tuple_t>::value>>
    bool operator()(actual_tuple_t&& actual) const noexcept {
      return compare_tuples_detail(equals(), expected, forward<actual_tuple_t>(actual), I());
    }
  };
```

As you might've guessed, I want this to compare the elements of my container to a stored reference element called `expected`.

Clearly, I can't pass `exactly` to `boost::make_filter_iterator` as a type parameter, as it's not default constructible. And I don't have a clue how to pass the constructed class to it like *Hey, I instantiated it for you, just call its `operator()`!*

This is the place where I would use it:

```
  template<class predicate_t, class vector_t>
  decltype(auto) filter_impl(vector_t&& v) noexcept {

    auto good = boost::make_iterator_range(
      boost::make_filter_iterator<predicate_t>(begin(forward<vector_t>(v)), end(forward<vector_t>(v))),
      boost::make_filter_iterator<predicate_t>(end(forward<vector_t>(v)), end(forward<vector_t>(v)))
    );

    return remove_reference_t<vector_t>(good.begin(), good.end());
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. `make_filter_iterator` can't do this, but `filter_iterator` has a constructor that takes a Predicate

```
template <class Predicate, class Iterator>
class filter_iterator
{
 public:
    typedef iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    typedef iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference reference;
    typedef iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer pointer;
    typedef iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef /* see below */ iterator_category;

    filter_iterator();
    filter_iterator(Predicate f, Iterator x, Iterator end = Iterator());
    filter_iterator(Iterator x, Iterator end = Iterator());
    template<class OtherIterator>
    filter_iterator(
        filter_iterator<Predicate, OtherIterator> const& t
        , typename enable_if_convertible<OtherIterator, Iterator>::type* = 0 // exposition
        );
    Predicate predicate() const;
    Iterator end() const;
    Iterator const& base() const;
    reference operator*() const;
    filter_iterator& operator++();
private:
    Predicate m_pred; // exposition only
    Iterator m_iter;  // exposition only
    Iterator m_end;   // exposition only
};
```

from the Boost docs.

So I need to call it like this:

```
  template<class predicate_t, class vector_t>
  decltype(auto) filter_impl(predicate_t&& p, vector_t&& v) noexcept {

    auto good = boost::make_iterator_range(
      boost::filter_iterator<predicate_t, decltype(begin(forward<vector_t>(v)))>
        (forward<predicate_t>(p), begin(forward<vector_t>(v)), end(forward<vector_t>(v))),
      boost::filter_iterator<predicate_t, decltype(begin(forward<vector_t>(v)))>
        (forward<predicate_t>(p), end(forward<vector_t>(v)), end(forward<vector_t>(v)))
    );

    return remove_reference_t<vector_t>(good.begin(), good.end());
  };
```